# High-Level Overview: How does Tex or LaTeX process documents?

Tags: latex

While there are whole StackExchanges devoted to [Tex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and a tag [`[tex]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex?sort=votes&pageSize=15) on here there is very little on the program itself.  The last time I tried to ask, I got cut off for misusing the phrase "TeX engine" - I was told it's not an engine.  My bad.

What are the steps in turning a TeX document into a file?  Even for just **a single equation** what are the steps TeX goes through to display that equation.

With some effort, I could find a book [Tex, the Program](http://brokestream.com/tex-web.html).  One possible answer could be just a summary. I am also intrigued that it's claimed to be an example of functional program, but that's not important. Thanks.

I would like to know why the code has not improved since 1982.  Why attempts to improve on TeX have failed.

Is the source code on GitHub anywhere? etc.

Comment: The code is in [`tex.web`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/knuth/dist/tex/tex.web); you'll compile `tex.web` using `weave tex.web` (with the WEB system installed).

Comment: I am a (La)TeX user for about twenty years now and although I am a programmer (C/C++) too, I actually don't care how the `TeX` binary is programmed at all, but I do care about that various `TeX` formats works (however, I am not part of the developer teams, of course)

Comment: I'll answer one of your questions here at once, _"I would like to know why the code has not improved since 1982. Why attempts to improve on TeX have failed."_. Because knuth'ing needs to be improved. Joke aside, [Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) is a very rigorous programmer/algorithm master, most likely the source of TeX (Web/pascal) was, within a few iterations, sufficiently awesome for generations to come.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Do you want to write an answer here?